Changing project CRS using PyQGIS not working
I have a fairly long PyQGIS script running in the Python Console Editor in QGIS. The script creates 5 layers:

3 layers derived from DEM data, generally in CRS EPSG:28356 (GDA94 / MGA Zone 56), and
2 layers derived from OSM data, in CRS EPSG:4326 (WGS84)

and saves them to a project. This all works fine.
At the very end of the script, I try to set the project CRS to the CRS of the DEM data, using the following line of code:
QgsProject.instance().setCrs(vlContour.crs())
where vlContour is the contour layer from DEM data, typically with CRS EPSG:28356.

However, regardless of this line of code, the CRS of the project ends up as EPSG:4236, which is not what I want.

If I run the single line of code directly in the Python Console, it works, and the CRS is changed to EPSG:28356
If I entirely remove the code that creates the 2 OSM layers from the script (these layers are in EPSG:4236) then the project CRS ends up as EPSG:28356 (!), rather than EPSG:4236
I have also tried setting the CRS elsewhere in the code - rather than the end - but this does not work either.

Can anyone suggest a way of getting the CRS change to stick in the PyQGIS script? It's not that hard to run the extra line manually, but it's certainly a nuisance!
A very very cut down version of the code, with one EPSG:28356 layer ('dem') and one EPSG:4326 layer ('osm_lines') is below. This is using QGIS 3.34.5, with GDAL 3.8. The final line is altered slightly, as it uses a different layer to try to set the CRS - but the issue is the same. I can run the final line directly in the Python Console, and it will change the CRS to EPSG:28356, but within the script it appears to do nothing.
bounds = 'C:/Users/brennant/Downloads/nattai-test_small.geojson'
output_dir = 'E:/geodata/'
output_file = 'nattai-test_small2'
input_dem = 'E:/geodata/_data/56h.vrt' # EPSG:28356 - virtual raster of DEMs in UTM Zone 56
osm_pbf_file = 'E:/geodata/ausosm.db' # EPSG:4326 - OSM PBF download, converted to Spatialite
path_to_gpkg = output_dir + output_file + '.gpkg'

#### DEM data (EPSG:28356)
resultClip = processing.run("gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer", { 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : input_dem, 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'MASK' : bounds, 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : None, 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None })['OUTPUT']
processing.run("gdal:translate",{ 'COPY_SUBDATASETS' : False, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '-co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=dem', 'INPUT' : resultClip, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : path_to_gpkg, 'TARGET_CRS' : None })['OUTPUT']
rlDem = iface.addRasterLayer("GPKG:" + path_to_gpkg + ":dem", "dem")
rlDem.setName('dem')

#### OSM data (EPSG:4326)
extent = rlDem.extent()
extentStr = "{},{},{},{} [{}]".format(extent.xMinimum(),extent.xMaximum(),extent.yMinimum(),extent.yMaximum(),rlDem.crs().authid())
resultOSMLines = processing.run("native:extractbyextent", { 'CLIP' : True, 'EXTENT' : extentStr, 'INPUT' : 'spatialite://dbname=\''+osm_pbf_file+'\' table=\"lines\" (geometry)', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' })['OUTPUT']
processing.run("gdal:convertformat", { 'INPUT' : resultOSMLines, 'OPTIONS' : '-update -nln osm_lines --config OGR2OGR_USE_ARROW_API NO', 'OUTPUT' : path_to_gpkg })
vlOSMLines = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_gpkg+'|layername=osm_lines', 'osm_lines', 'ogr')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlOSMLines)

#### Save project
QgsProject.instance().write(output_dir + output_file +'.qgz')

QgsProject.instance().setCrs(rlDem.crs())


It will be difficult to get help without indicating the QGIS version used and providing the PyQGIS script.

are the OSM layers tiles or vector?

Code sample added. OSM data source is a OSM PBF extract, converted to Spatialite format using ogr2ogr.

This appears to be caused by:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/27139
Essentially the setCrs call is overridden by other queued events that happen before the script completes.
The workaround proposed by Nyall Dawson in the discussion on the issue is to wrap the code in the following way:
prev_setting = iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().autoSetupOnFirstLayer()
iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().setAutoSetupOnFirstLayer(False)

# add layers, set crs, etc

def post_steps():
    iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().setAutoSetupOnFirstLayer(prev_setting)

QTimer.singleShot(500, lambda: post_steps)

I'm not sure what it's doing and why, but empirical testing suggests that it works.
